# Rounding an image and positioning it with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image like this one:

[image]

I want to apply a rounded effect on the green part (I have added the black border so you can see what the image looks like) but as you can see from the code below it does not put the green part in the center, one side of it is chopped off.

```css
img {
    border-radius: 90px;
    -o-border-radius: 90px;
    -moz-border-radius: 90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXL5.png">
```

I'm not sure what property I could use to reach the desired effect or how I could round it keeping the green part in the center.  using CSS only hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it as a background image and adjust the needed properties :

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXL5.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-size:125% 125%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Could I say I could position any image in this way?

Comment: @Simon i would say yes. using the background-position with predefined values like top right, etc or by specifing pixel values ... then you control the size with background size. So you can control any positon of any image with this way

Comment: Ok.  It makes sense that it does. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 5):

> **you can do it this way to clean the edges for nice look** :

```css
#roundImg {
    border-radius:100% !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100%;
     
    border:2px solid #C9C9C9;
    width: 90px;
    height:90px;
   
   overflow: hidden;
  
  
} #roundImg img {
         position :relative; 
         top:-18px;  right:55px;
         }
```

```html
<div id="roundImg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXL5.png">
</div>
```

> **or you can mess with the (width & height & top & right ) to let the sharp edges show up :**

```css
#roundImg {
    border-radius:100% !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100%;
     
    border:2px solid #C9C9C9;
    width: 110px;
    height:110px;
   
   overflow: hidden;
  
  
} #roundImg img {
         position :relative;
         top:-8px;  right:44px;
         }
```

```html
<div id="roundImg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXL5.png">
</div>
```